# RangeBarChart plotted over time in aChartEngine

Tags: java, android, achartengine

What I'd like to do is have a `RangeBarChart` with it's X-axis as dates. Currently adding new bars to a `RangeCategorySeries` spaces each bar equally, and there doesn't appear to be a mechanism for manually specifying an X value, such as a Date. `TimeSeries` exists, but appears only to be for `LineCharts`.

Ideally what I'd need is a method `add(min, max, date)` on `RangeCategorySeries`.

Has anyone implemented this or have some tips for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend `RangeCategorySeries` and override `toXYSeries()`. I've pasted the current implementation of this method below for your reference. You can try changing this by setting the X value according to the date at each index.

```
public XYSeries toXYSeries() {
  XYSeries xySeries = new XYSeries(getTitle());
  int length = getItemCount();
  for (int k = 0; k < length; k++) {
    xySeries.add(k + 1, getMinimumValue(k));
    // the new fast XYSeries implementation doesn't allow 2 values at the same X,
    // so I had to do a hack until I find a better solution
    xySeries.add(k + 1.000001, getMaximumValue(k));
  }
  return xySeries;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! This works great. I simply added a new method  `add(double minValue, double maxValue, Date date)`, maintain a list of the added dates, then retrieve the date value and call `getTime()` on it instead of using the `k` value in `toXYSeries()`.